# Laravel SQL Query

Tags: laravel, controller, eloquent

I have sample database

```
id    |      Name      |     Email           |      Group 
1          John Doe      jdemo@yahoo.com              A
2          Robert Chow   robertdemo@gmail.com         B
3          Lee Tee       leedemo@aol.com              C
```

I use autocomplete(Ajax for search and  to show data on table)

On my SearchController

This is my Code

```
 if ($request->ajax()) {
     $output = "";
     $orderinfo=DB::table('tb_client')
         ->where('email','LIKE','%' .$request->search. '%' )
         ->orWhere('id','LIKE','%' .$request->search. '%')
         ->orWhere('group','LIKE','%' .$request->search. '%')
         ->get();
}
```

I want to have  filter this that Only Group (A)
should be listed on my html table

so if user search for Lee Tee it will show not belong to your Area ,

Comment: If you want to filter by the group, then why does the group not appear in your `WHERE` clause?  Please make your question more clear.

Comment: please, show your HTML form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your where clause :

```
$orderinfo = DB::table('tb_client')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('email','LIKE','%' .$request->search. '%')
              ->orWhere('id','LIKE','%' .$request->search. '%');
        })
    ->where('group', 'A')
    ->get();
```

Also I don't recommend to use LIKE on id field!

Comment: Change 2nd line to `->where(function ($query) use ($request) {`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change your "where" clause for id, because it will show you incorrect results. For example, if you search 1 and there are records going up to 100+, all those results will show up.

Secondly, for your query, you can specify it in your where clause like this

```
->where('group' , '=' , 'A')->get();
```